# call a method from another fragment by view pager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity

I have two fragment class (#1 and #2) in my fragment activity.The fragment activity is used in view pager.
How can i call a method of fragment#2 in fragment#1?
Please, notice the attached picture.

http://upload7.ir/imgs/2014-09/92109715706282282966.jpg

Comment: This is a design flaw.  Fragments aren't meant to be dependent on other fragments.   I didn't see the viewpager in your picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred way is to let all communication between Fragments go trough their common parent Activity:

```
public class MyActivity implements WantsACalledListener {

    private Fragment fragment2;        

    @Override
    public onWantsACalled() {
        fragment2.a();
    }

}
```

And, according to the Android documentation at: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

```
public static class Fragment1 {
    WantsACalledListener mListener;
    ...
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (WantsACalledListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement WantsACalledListener");
        }
    }
    ...

    private void someMethod() {
        mListener.onWantsACalled();
    }
}
```

So, the Activity can easily keep a reference to all its child Fragments and the child Fragments get the reference to their parent Activity in their onAttach method.